# Problems with xampp server

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I work with xampp for localhost wordpress web page, but xampp is getting lower and lower.

There are something I would do to fix it? Or you can say other program to work in local with wordpress?

Thanks you. :)

Comment: try [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use updated version of xammp:https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html